# Storing text inside a span referenced by id

Tags: javascript

Need a little help for a web development project, we're still doing very elementary stuff.

I have a bunch of empty spans with `id`s like `guess1`, `guess2`, `guess3` and so on. I'm trying to store user input `playerGuess` into the innerHTML of the next empty one every time they enter their input, but I really don't understand how to. I've tried doing something like

```
"guess" + guessnumber.innerHTML = playerGuess
```

or something like

```
test = "guess" + guessnumber

test.innerHTML = playerGuess
```

I vaguely understand why neither are working, so can anyone help explain how I can properly format it? Thank you!

Comment: Check out w3schools library: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_html_innerhtml.asp

Comment: If you're looking for some good example code, here's a fiddle demonstrating a few related techniques: https://jsfiddle.net/fxxztaww/ Note the use of `.textContent` instead of `.innerHTML`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a span:

```
<span id="guess1"></span>
```

You can get the guess with:

```
playerGuess = window.prompt("Guess: ");
```

Or from an input, like so:

```
playerGuess = document.getElementById("guess-input").value;
```

There is probably a loop to keep track of how many guesses are made:

```
var i = 0;
while (i < MAX_TRIES && playerGuess !== target) {
    playerGuess = prompt("Guess: ");
    i++;
}
```

And you need to put the guess in the span with:

```
document.getElementById("guess"+i).textContent = playerGuess;
```

These are the pieces.  You can do it.

Be sure to declare all your variables with **var** and initialize any constants.

Comment: The demonstration of `.textContent` is appropriate, but why are you torturing us with a looping prompt? `:P`

Comment: One may want to add a confirm as well

Answer (score 1):

Wrong way around.

```
var playerGuess = "guess" + guessnumber.innerHTML;
```